# Is there a way to define routes in a YAML file for a Spring project?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

I've been working a lot with Symfony recently, and I really like the ability to define routes in a [`routing.yml`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#creating-routes-in-yaml-xml-or-php-files) file. I was looking into Spring's routing system and I couldn't find any options other than placing routes in annotations on controller methods. Is it possible to accomplish something like this in Spring?

My first thought was creating an abstract controller that grabs the routes from a `.yml` file, but that seemed a bit hacky.

#### EDIT:

For some added context, I am looking to build a simple Database API with Spring. After some digging it looks like the `routing.yml` file is best suited for working with server-rendered pages, which is *not* what I aim to do with my Spring project.

Comment: there is no out of the box solution for what you are looking for AFAIK. You could implement it yourself but seems easier just to follow standard path of defining controllers and routes

Answer (score 0):

Symfony and Spring are different framework. You are used to one use and want to use same it in another entirely different system. It will not work. You have to adapt to frameworks.

Spring will scan your project and collect your specific annotation like Controller/Component/Configuration/... and configures itself. Therefore, there is no need predefined project structure, unlike, for example, Laravel. So, you can define this structure if you want. Or every class can be in one package, just not beautiful.

Back to routing. You can configure them by the value of annotations only. This is interpreted at compile time. (Ofc, there are runtime annotations, but I focused parameters of annotation.) So, you can not use configuration from the file because it is already runtime. So, you should use constants or hardcode.

Or, you can use an alternative: Annotate the interfaces, then the controllers will be the implementations.

Alternative #2: If you use Spring with Kotlin, In Kotlin, you can have several classes or interfaces in one file.